# How to leave Voice mail using Twilio?

Tags: salesforce, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'am trying to send recorded messages to phone numbers using twilio & salesforce. The problem i am facing that some times the call is going to Voice mail and the message is not getting recorded as the voice mail recording starts after a certain time. How can twilio manage to monitor that time and play the message after the voice mail starts recording.

Now i know that the voice mail recording system uses a beep before it starts recording. Can i use that DTMF tone to instruct twilio to start playing the recorded message.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio is able to do some, experimental, checking for answering machines such that it will only start playing after it hears a beep. You can see how to do this in the [documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#handling-outcomes-answering-machines). Basically, you need to pass an ifMachine parameter of "Continue". You will then get an "AnsweredBy" parameter in calls to your TwiML so that you can decide what to do. If you do continue, Twilio will wait for the beep.

Let me know if that helps!

**Update**

The `ifMachine` parameter has been deprecated and replaced with the new [Twilio Answering Machine Detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/answering-machine-detection).

Now you can pass a parameter called `MachineDetection` with the argument `Enable` or `DetectMessageEnd`. `Enable` tries to give you an answer as soon as possible, passing the result to the TwiML webhook within the `AnsweredBy` parameter. `DetectMessageEnd` will call the webhook once the voicemail message has finished playing.

Comment: I read about this in your documents & I used this trick by myself but I think that is not working with my case..I will give it a try again and let you know

Comment: I got a workaround for this problem. Its not 100% neat.We can loop our message for a number of times and prompt to disconnect the call by pressing a specific button. A human will listen to the prompt and disconnect the call after hearing the message. Where as a machine will not able to do that and the message will get recorded at some iteration of the message.

Comment: I don't see an ifMachine parameter in the API. How do I send that?

Comment: `ifMachine` is an old parameter that is being deprecated. If you are looking for answering machine detection, then our new and improved API is all explained here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/answering-machine-detection

Comment: philnash, based on the link you provided, it appears that the ifmachine option is being deprecated.  I seem to be having a hard time finding information on how to handle the situation going forward.  I have machine detection enabled, but can't seem to find a way to tell Twilio to 'wait for the beep', as it were.  Recommendations?

Comment: Hey Jeffrey, check the comment just above here for the up to date answering machine detection documentation. To wait for the beep you want to set `MachineDetection` to `DetectMessageEnd`.

Comment: can you leave voicemail directly instead of only if there is an answer machine?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer yes, you can return whatever TwiML you want given the response.

Comment: I don't want call to ring at all if possible, i just want to leave a voice mail. Dial -> leave voice message.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer There is not a method that skips ringing a phone. You can't just go straight to voicemail. You should handle the person answering the phone or the voicemail answering. And don't forget to handle if the person doesn't answer and doesn't have voicemail.